# Web API oData Patch function with jQuery results in XML Parsing Error?

Tags: jquery, .net, odata, patch

I am working with Web API oData for the first time and running into issues calling a patch request.  I am attempting to use the patch request to update an existing record in the database.

I have not modified the default Patch controller generated in Visual Studio.

```
[AcceptVerbs("PATCH", "MERGE")]
    public IHttpActionResult Patch([FromODataUri] int key, Delta<SubGroup> patch)
    {
        Validate(patch.GetEntity());

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        SubGroup subGroup = db.SubGroups.Find(key);
        if (subGroup == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        patch.Patch(subGroup);

        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!SubGroupExists(key))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return Updated(subGroup);
    }
```

My jQuery looks like:

```
$(document).on('click', '#submitEditSubGroup', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formValues = $("#EditSubGroupForm").serialize();
    postForm(formValues, "patch", "odata/SubGroups("+$("#editSubGroupID").val()+")");
});


function postForm(formValues,requestType,odata) {       
    $.ajax({
        url: odata,
        type: requestType,
        data: formValues,
        success: function (response) {
           //Data updated successfully
        }
    });
}
```

When testing my patch request is calling the following url:

```
..../odata/SubGroups(1)
```

and the resulting XML displays:

```
XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: moz-nullprincipal:{a2ec8bbc-3452-461a-b0f0-44369d021849} Line Number 1, Column 1:
```